# How can you access your entities's getters and setters?

Tags: javascript, jsp

so i have this jsp, i created a function in javascript that accepts an `ArrayList<Product>` as a parameter. and i am wondering if i can access my entities's getters and setters inside my script tags. is it possible? i have this code:

```
        function compute(products) {
            var productid1 = document.getElementById("product1").value;
            var productquantity1= document.getElementById("productquantity1").value;
            var price = 0;
            var isDone = false;
            for(var i = 0; i < products.size() && isDone === false; i++) {
                if(products.get(i).getProductID === productid1) {
                    price = products.get(i).getProductPrice() * productquantity1;
                    isDone = true;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("totalPrice").value = parseInt(price);
        }
```

and i have this inside my `<table>` in the body

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Total Price: <input type="text" id="totalPrice">
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: It is not possible to have Gutter and Sutters

Comment: If you mean getters and setters in Java code, no, not directly. The Java code runs on the server and the Javascript code runs on the client. By the time the Javascript code runs, the Java code has already finished.

Comment: do you have alternative solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript typically runs at client side. It arrives there as a plain text exactly like HTML. There is no relationships between objects and classes at server and client side. Therefore this line:

`price = products.get(i).getProductPrice() * productquantity1;`

will not and cannot work.

To make it working you have to serialize content of your list created at server side and somehow transfer it to client. There are frameworks that can help you to do this. Basically you have to create javascript objects corresponding to the classes at server side and populate them. Typically frameworks that do this work asynchronously via AJAX.

Take a look for example on [ExtDirect](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/extdirect). I am not sure that it is good for you since it is a a Spring extension, so it requires Spring framework on server side. However it can be a good starting point and you can search for other similar solution that will be good for your.